# JOGL drawArrays JRE error

Tags: java, jogl

I encountered a problem when working with JOGL. Here is the code and error message:

```
@Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_QUADS, 0, 4); // error
        for (Model.VerticesDescriptor vd : model.vd) {
            //if (vd.POLYTYPE == vd.POLY_TYPE_TRIANGLES) gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, vd.START, vd.END); // error
            //if (vd.POLYTYPE == vd.POLY_TYPE_QUADS) gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_QUADS, vd.START, vd.END); // error
            //else if (vd.POLYTYPE == vd.POLY_TYPE_POLYGON) gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_POLYGON, vd.START, vd.END); // error
        }
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    }
```

Error message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007efd2dd1fe23, pid=7101, tid=0x00007efcc6bda700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x128e23]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/congard/Разработка/eclipse-workspace/Turbo Fly 3D/hs_err_pid7101.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

With what this problem can be connected? Here is the code I am making buffers (located in the init function):

```
vertices = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(model.vertices.length);
        vertices.put(model.vertices).position(0);

        texCoords = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(model.texCoords.length);
        texCoords.put(model.texCoords).position(0);

        normals = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(model.normals.length);
        normals.put(model.normals).position(0);
```

There are ~5000 elements in these buffers

Comment: When I'd get errors like this in LWJGL, the problem is usually that I'm connecting two buffers that are the wrong type, or an operation and a buffer where the buffer is the wrong type.  Try removing draw calls until the error goes away, then focus on the last part changed, especially its declared (to OpenGL) type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the error was on this line

```
gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
```

I changed it to

```
gl.glNormalPointer(GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
```

And everything work now